# Creating custom function in QGIS with self intersects

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-custom-function

I'm trying to create some customs functions in QGIS to automate some works I'm doing in my job.
I have some experience using QGIS expression but I'm trying to create some custom functions now.

I have a layer of points with covid cases and I'm agreggating this points suming the cases depending on the scale of map canvas, as you can see in the expression below:

**aggregate( @layer_name, 'sum', "susp_atv" , intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent),0.004 @map_scale ))**

Now I'm having trouble trying to transform this in a custom function.
The function below checks if all geometries of a layer intersects with any geometries of another layer.

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def intersect(layer_name, feature, parent):

    teste = False
    geom = feature.geometry()
    layer = QgsProject.instance.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        if geom.intersects(feat.geometry()):
            teste=True
            break

    return teste
```

How can I update this code to perform the self intersect buffer that I need.